# incoming and current in a rebase

Tags: git, rebase

There is a similar question to this one but its scope is too general and the response overly complicated.
My question is *very punctual*

When from my branch `MyBranch` and doing a rebase like `git rebase  master`
and having a conflict

which is *incoming change*? and which is *current change*?

Please don't close this question linking it to previously said overly general and overly complicated answer that covers rebases, merges, etc. This question is *ONLY* about rebase

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> When from my branch `MyBranch` and doing a rebase like `git rebase master` and having a conflict which is incoming change? and which is current change?

When rebasing `MyBranch` onto `master`, "incoming" is the branch you have checked out, which is `MyBranch`, and "current" is `master`.

The reason is because of what rebase actually does behind the scenes. Rebase first resets your branch to `master`, and then replays each of the commits from `MyBranch` onto `master`. If there is a conflict while doing that rebase, then **at that moment**, `master` is now your temporary "current" and `MyBranch` is "incoming" because you're replaying those commits. Once the rebase completes you'll have `MyBranch` checked out again and back to where it would be considered "current" again.

The reason the explanation is oftentimes included with merging, is because the labels are flipped, and are perhaps more intuitive, for `merge`. "Incoming" is the branch you're merging in, and "current" is your branch.