# git rebase --strategy=ours use case clarification

Tags: git, rebase

I maintain a fork where all of my changes on top of the upstream repo I have scripted so that they can be re-applied arbitrarily. In order to pull in the upstream repo's changes, I want to rebase, and in the case of any conflict, completely discard my file and use the upstream's version since I can just re-apply whatever necessary.

According to the git documentation, I think I want
`git rebase -s ours upstream/master`

If I look at the docs for the `strategy-option` for `ours`

> This should not be confused with the ours merge strategy, which does not even look at what the other tree contains at all. It discards everything the other tree did, declaring our history contains all that happened in it.

This sounds like exactly what I want, assuming that the `ours`/`theirs` flip still applies here.

The docs for the `ours` strategy seem to confirm:

> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches

However, when I look the docs for `--strategy`:

> Because git rebase replays each commit from the working branch on top of the `<upstream>` branch using the given strategy, using the ours strategy simply empties all patches from the `<branch>`, which makes little sense.

I'm not sure I totally understand what it means by it `empties all patches`

It it just saying that it makes little sense for *most* people simply because it will discard their own changes they have made?

When using `git rebase -s ours`, does `ours` still refer to the upstream branch?

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:** There isn't a built in way to do *exactly* what you want, and `git rebase -s ours` is a pointless option.

### The Long Story

The merge strategy `-s ours` basically merges in commits, without taking any changes. It's something you might use if you want to make older historical branches reachable from another branch, without actually bringing in the changes. A possible use case is when you wish to partially merge in the newer portion of a branch, without also merging in some older commits in the history of that same branch. You could use `git merge -s ours <top-commit-to-ignore>`, and then merge in the branch to bring in changes for only the later set of commits after the ignored commits. (This has a high probability of conflicts though, unless the newer commits are pretty well isolated from the ignored commits.)

The reason it doesn't make sense to use `-s ours` with a rebase, is because `-s ours` is basically just merging in the commit IDs themselves, and with rebase you are rewriting the commit IDs, so there are no commit IDs to preserve. Essentially you're going to do a hard reset to the target commit, and then skip the rebase of all your commits, meaning the end result is equivalent to just doing the hard reset in the first place. For example:

```
git rebase -s ours main

# is the same as
git reset --hard main
```

The only difference is the rebase will take longer than the reset, and you'll see a bunch of messages saying "dropping  ..." as it iterates through all of your commits that it will drop. (Btw, that's what is meant by "empties all patches".) This is why the documentation states using `-s ours` with rebase "makes little sense".

### What's up with the documention?

IMHO you've stumbled upon one of the most confusing parts of the Git documentation, and the reason is (I think) because it's difficult to notice that the "ours" and "theirs" options are slightly indented compared to the "ort" merge strategy. This is because "ours" and "theirs" are additional options to the `-s ort` strategy, which is the default if you don't specify it. These options are actually passed with `-X ours` or `-X theirs`. The text under `ours`:

> This should not be confused with the `ours` merge strategy...

is another way of saying:

> Right now you are currently reading about the `-X ours` strategy, which should not be confused with the `-s ours` merge strategy which is something completely different.

**Side Note:** there is no equivalent `-s theirs` merge strategy.

### What can you do?

Unfortunately, you can't quite do what you wish:

> In order to pull in the upstream repo's changes, I want to rebase, and in the case of any conflict, completely discard my file and use the upstream's version since I can just re-apply whatever necessary.

But maybe conflict resolution with `-X ours` will get you close? The biggest difference here is that the `-X` conflict resolution only chooses "ours" (upstream) or "theirs" (your branch) *at the hunks that are conflicted*, rather than for the entire file. So when you use `git rebase -Xours`, if some of your changes in a file can be merged in cleanly, but the same file has conflicts in a different part of the file, your changes will be merged when possible, and the upstream's changes will be selected at the conflicting hunks. You said your desire is to "completely discard my file" but that's not quite what will happen. That being said, if you are planning to "just re-apply whatever necessary", this will get you closer to that goal.

**Side Note:** in case after reading the paragraph above, you are wondering why "ours" and "theirs" appear to flipped when rebasing, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71332146/184546).

Comment: thanks! I was aware of the reasoning behind the ours/theirs flip (and the strategy-option vs strategy), I just couldn't completely grok the documentation differences between the sections but this clarifies it for me. much appreciated